# Mongoid, has_and_belongs_to_many, two sided association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have created model which has custom `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :combinations, class_name: 'Item', inverse_of: :combinations
end
```

If I have `item1` and `item2`, when I do something like this:

```
 item1.combinations << item2
 item1.save

 item1.combinations # returns [<Item2>]
 item2.combinations # returns []
```

This means that associations are **one-sided**. How to make this association two sided? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I didnt test it but should work.

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :child_combinations, class_name: 'Item', inverse_of: :parent_combinations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parent_combinations, class_name: 'Item', inverse_of: :child_combinations
end
```

Then you can access like this

```
item1.child_combinations
item2.parent_combinations
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Is it possible to use only one `has_and_belongs_to_many` assocation?

Comment: No its not possible because mongoid needs two way association. You have to specify how the relations are made. So if you just mention one `has_and_belongs_to _many`, mongoid looks for the relation specified in the related model and if it doesnt find, it doesnt create the relationship.

Comment: And also you cant combine parent and child combinations in one array. You need to specify two different for parent and child else it ll always be one sided.

Comment: But why when I want to associate with diffrent model it only requires one `has_and_belongs_to_many`?